# Best way to handle a ratings system

Tags: algorithm, database-design

I'm trying to implement a comparison rating system and I'm having difficulties finding the best way to handle this, especially from a database perspective.

Let's use food for an example.

The user is given pictures of two different foods and he chooses which one he likes better. He is then shown two more foods (one could be the same or they could both be different) and the user again selects. He continues to do this over and over and in doing so the application will TELL the user what his favorite food is, based solely on him saying which ones he likes more than others and comparing all these comparisons and displaying the results.

I've thought of just keeping track of the total likes/dislikes of each item, and I've also considered keeping track of every single choice in a massive database. I'm sure there's a way I've overlooked that is efficient for this kind of system.

Basically I'm looking not only for an efficient algorithm but also the best way to store this in a database.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: But what happens when you show a Developer an image of Pizza and one of doughnuts? How's he supposed to make a choice?

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: I consider of showing people pictures of animals to determine what job he's currently have, how many children he will have and whether he likes The Beatles. How should I do this? (Sorry for the sarcasm, I couldn't resist.)

Comment: there would be categories for types of food, like main courses, deserts, etc.

Comment: I would first clearly define how you want the rating to work and then think about database implementation, for e.g. think about how are you going to handle ratings when a particular image has been shown 1000 times compared to one that has been only shown 100 times. Can the user skip? Is a choice both a downvote for the non selected image and an upvote for the selected image or just one of those? Does a food item suffer less penalty if it is not chosen against the most favorite choice or get higher rating if it gets upvoted then? These will define your rating system and eventually the databse

Comment: In order to help you with this you should describe the algorithm in a bit more detail: 1. the mechanism itself 2. is it online/offline? 3. amount and type of data

Comment: Okay let me expand the idea so you can better assist. It is online and multi-user. Each individual user can see his/her own rankings and it might surprise users to see their results. Then users can also see the global rankings on what the averaged "favorite" foods are. Also, the user cannot skip a ranking ever, but can choose an option that both pictures are about equal. If the user has chosen he likes pizza 1000 times and spaghetti once, but the one spaghetti vote was versus pizza and higher than pizza, then the spaghetti would be higher on the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just keep a database of triplets `(user_id, preferred_id, dispreferred_id)` corresponding to each choice.

EDIT: Had a bit of time to play with this. The following would be slow for millions of ratings, and gobble up memory, too, but might give you ideas. If you do go with this, you should probably run in asynchronously from crontab, rather by on-demand.

```
require 'set'                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

choices = [
  [1, 4],
  [1, 5],
  [2, 3],
  [2, 4],
  [3, 1],
  [4, 2],
  [4, 3],
  [5, 1],
  [6, 7],
  [8, 4],
]

dominates = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new }
choices.each do |p, d|
  dominates[p].add(d)
end

prev_dominates = nil
while dominates != prev_dominates
  prev_dominates = Hash.new
  dominates.each { |big, smalls| prev_dominates[big] = smalls.clone }
  prev_dominates.each do |big, smalls|
    smalls.each do |small|
      if prev_dominates.include?(small)
        prev_dominates[small].each do |smaller|
          if smaller != big and !prev_dominates[smaller].include?(big)
            dominates[big] << smaller
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

top = dominates.max_by { |big, smalls| smalls.size }[0]

puts dominates.inspect
puts "BEST: #{top}"
```

The top node is the one that ends up dominating the most other nodes. However, given that the graph can be cyclic, we cut the cycle if another node would have completed the cycle sooner.

Comment: @Mitch - there would be categories for types of food. Like main course, desert, etc.

Comment: @JonathanPlumb: I am not Mitch :p

Comment: what happens if it's not food and it's something like celebrities, and there's been millions or even eventually billions of comparisons combined between many users ... would you recommend a different database approach in this case?

Comment: Sorry Amadan -- there was another comment by "Mitch Wheat" where he asked what happens if there's pizza and a doughnut.

Comment: Amadan, I've implemented something similar to what you recommended. However, I'm struggling with actually ranking everything once I have a huge list of likes/dislikes. That's the algorithm I was needing help with.

Comment: @JonathanPlumb: Added an algorithm. Probably not an optimal algorithm. :p